# Android restart my activity

Tags: android, android-context

How can I do that?

on button click:

```
mycontext.finish();
```

and then: start again?

Comment: This is not really intended behaviour. What are you trying to accomplish by restarting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try either this:

```
MyActivity.finish()
Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, MyActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Or if that doesn't work, you could do this:

```
private boolean isRestarting = false;
...
// When button is pressed
isRestarting = true;
myactivity.finish();
...
// in the onDestroy() method
if(isFinishing() && isRestarting){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, MyActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```