# Display battery level on notifications bar when i check the check button

Tags: android, android-notifications, battery, batterylevel

i want to display the battery level (like: 50%), in the notifications bar. I want it when a check box is pressed because i want to decide if display it or not. Anyway, i use this code for the battery level  :

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    BroadcastReceiver batteryReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        int level = -1;
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
            Log.e("BatteryManager", "level is "+level+");
        }
    };
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(batteryReceiver, filter);
    }
```

And to post the notification i found this one:

```
   NotificationManager notifi = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

   Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Testing",System.currentTimeMillis());

   notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

   Intent i = new Intent(this,KillerActivity.class); 

   PendingIntent penInt = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0 , i , 0);

   notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "Varaha ", "Testing", penInt);

   notifi.notify(215,notification);
```

But how can i merge it with my code for the barrey level?

Comment: where is `batteryReceiver` code? put notification code into that

Comment: In the onRecive? Or over that?

Comment: But just copy the code i wrote about the notification? Have i to change something?

Comment: Really i don't know how can do. For example this li `Intent i = new Intent(this,KillerActivity.class);` is it necessary? What have i to write? The killeActivity of course it's not in my project..

Comment: No. actually this says that when user cllicks on notification which Activity should open. So you should write your own activity to show when user clicks on notification. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769192/start-new-activity-from-notification-in-android

Comment: But for the check box button?how can i do?