# Pending Intent not working

Tags: android, push-notification, android-pendingintent

I know the question i am asking is a duplicate. But i have tried all sorts of things. All i want is, MainActivity class to get called when i click on the notification. My code is,

```
private void sendNotification(String msg) 
{
    Log.d(TAG, "Preparing to send notification...: " + msg);
    int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP); 

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestID,notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                                            .setContentTitle("Hashtag")
                                            .setContentText(msg)
                                            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                                            .setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mBuilder.setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 });
    mBuilder.setLights(Color.RED, 3000, 3000);
    mBuilder.setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

    mNotificationManager.notify((int)Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), mBuilder.build());
    Log.e("NEW NOTIFICATION ID IS --- ", String.valueOf((int)Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()));
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification sent successfully.");
}
```

My MainActivity Class is as follows,

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    loadUrl(launchUrl);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is my Toast!!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I want the toast to be called. Please people.. help me out !! This has been killing me for the whole day..!!!

Comment: your toast wont fire because that activity is not being recreated due to the SIngleTop. It will reuse the existing one.

Comment: Instead of SingleTop, use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, then the activity will be displayed.

Comment: @e4c5 Ohh.. is there any other way to get the toast?

Comment: Not quite sure if you ought to use new task flag as suggested in the answer given. You can get the toast by moving that code into the onResume() method. It will solve the problem but that may not be ideal either, it all depends on what your activity is about (which we don't know). I think a bit of reading on activity life cycles is in order.

Comment: @e4c5 When i click on the notification, i want to call a function in javascript. That's my need.

Comment: @AnithaManikandan Tried it.. no luck :/

Comment: Well you would need a lot more code for that. The basic stategy is to put an intent extra and your onResume method can check for it's existence and call loadUrl("javascript:something") for that you will need to read up on the WebView

Comment: @e4c5 Can you show me a sample code.. cause i am new to this..

Comment: sorry no. Sample code will not help you. THere is no substitute for reading the documentation. You absolutely have to read the WebView documentation and the LifeCycle documentation. I am voting to close this question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Start new activity from notification in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769192/start-new-activity-from-notification-in-android)

Comment: @e4c5 Ok, thanks for the replies.. I will go through the document.. i asked the sample for the onResume.. not the WebView

Comment: When you read the documentation you will find plenty of samples in there

Answer (score 0):

For showing toast, use below line.

```
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

in place of,

```
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Comment: Tried it.. No change.. Still the same